# Testing versions of dependencies in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

To make the modules less dependent of specific versions, I would like to test the modules with different versions of the dependencies so I can determine the 'corners' of the version box the module will work happily in.

e.g. the module is built in against library foo.bar 2.1.2. Then the tool should test 2.0.0 and if it fails the versions in between like git bisect. Then similar between 2.1.2 and whatever the latest version is. Then do that with the next dependency.

I found that it is often rather trivial to extend the range of versions by tweaking how the library is being used. When deploying to an OSGi container, running in a wide set of versions per dependency makes life a lot less painful. However manually testing so many combinations is an absolute nightmare.

Does anybody know of such a tool so it can run on a CI server at night?

PS: I know such a tool would have all kinds of gnarly edge case and imperfections. I just want to reduce the amount of assumptions that are implicitely being made when building modules. Normal testing will catch these weird cases anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "testing all combinations" ? All combinations of dependencies, or a dependency VS a set of containers?

Comment: I do not think it is useful to test all combinations. Just find the smallest and biggest version around the version in the POM which still pass the tests. Testing on multiple containers can then be done based on these results.

Comment: Its a very interesting question, but I have troubles finding the scope. I especially have troubles with the fact that there are not just "dependencies", Maven is built around the idea of transient dependencies which you do not even define in your own poms. One dependency generally translates into a host of dependencies - with very specific versions.

Comment: Do I have this right? With _"all combinations"_  of _"versions in between"_ >= 2.0.0 and <=2.1.2, i.e. 2.[0..1].[0..2], this would be 6 full Maven build lifecycles for this one dependency? And 20 if it is 2.[0..1].[0..9] in the near future. And 800 if it is [2..9][0..9][0..9] in the distant future?

Comment: I edited the question, since the word 'all' in the illustration of what happens if you do it manually seems to pull in the wrong direction. I think that for practical purposes if it works on 2.0.0 and 2.1.2, it will likely work on all version in between. So the tool only needs to find the edge versions where it breaks. In the best case it would be 2.0.0 and whatever is the latest in the 2.x.x version range. In the worst case it would have to look with a binary search for the breaking version, which is O(log(N)), with N the number of versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jenkins Matrix Project Plugin - see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project

In your pom.xml define the version as a property.

```
<properties>
  <my.version>1.30</my.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>${my.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then provide a test version with each iteration of the Jenkins Matrix.

```
mvn test -Dmy.version=1.31
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this. It is not going to look for the versions, but it might be a pragmatic approach till something fancier is found. With a lot of dimensions this might get out of control, as the number of combinations is O(2^m) with m the number of dependencies to test for. (in practice half a dozen).